# iframe Fits complete webpage as on Full HD Screen in to a small Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

[image]

[image]

In first Picture I have 6 iframes being loaded and each having its own HTML page. All pages in those iframes are responsive so they got adjust as per the size.

But I want to make it look like exactly the same those HTML pages would look in 1920x1080 resolution screen (shown in image 2)

Image 2 is the HTML page being loaded in the second row first iframe of Image 1

Answer (score 0):

You can set the high resolution to the frame by default and then zoom and scale it down to the required size.

All you have to do is calculate zoom/scale from starting width to required width.
Which should be required width divided by starting width.

[Source of the code with examples.](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-scale-the-content-of-iframe-element.html)

```
#your-frame {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}

#your-frame {
  zoom: 0.50;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.50);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.50);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.50);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #your-frame {
    zoom: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set the size to iframes. The code below helped me without any problems:

CSS Code:

```
div {
  width: 31%;
  height: 294px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
iframe {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
}
```

[image]